# How to post at a time on multiple wordpress sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two websites based on wordpress plateform.

1. www.sciencekidunya.com
2. jahanescience.com

I am administrating both of the websites but the problem is that both have different themes, and when I have to post an essay, first I post it to first website and then same post to the second website. It is a tiring process. Is there anyway to just post on 1 website and it automatically get posted on the all others too?

Please tell me the procedure of doing so. thanks

Comment: this plugin can help you, [Push Syndication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-syndication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out below links:

This is the wordpress plugin which you can install and do what you want.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/

This explain in details the entire step to achieve your goal.
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-publish-to-multiple-wordpress-sites-from-a-single-install/?utm_expid=3606929-78.ZpdulKKETQ6NTaUGxBaTgQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have two different site so i assume there must have two different Database. so logically we can not combine two different site and Database.

but there is one way i think where you need to create separate Admin panel and make some functions which post your article in both database.

Comment: is there any query to make the different schemas compatible by force (some sort of mapping by sql)?